# The actual meaning of おっさん臭い

Tags: japanese-to-english, metaphor

I think おっさん臭い literally means 'old man stench', if I'm not mistaken, but it seems like the actual meaning is different.

For example, in this episode of ちびまる子ちゃん Tomo says

> "なんかちょっとおっさん臭い気がするけど"

after (if my listening comprehension is correct) a classmate with a weirdly formal style of speech tells her that doing certain eye exercises will open up a 3rd eye that can predict the future.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNi54uQEr60&t=366s

And then in the show 推しの子 at the end of episode 1 at timestamp 1:19:13(spoilers for episode 1)

> Aqua, the brother says:

> > "スカート短すぎないか？"

> To which his sister Ruby replies :

> > "お兄ちゃんって昔からおっさん臭いよね"

Is おっさん臭い used to mean 'creepy', 'weirdo', or does it have some other meaning(s)

Comment: Oh, the first one is 胡散(うさん)臭い, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix くさい makes up i-adjective meaning "have similar appearance/behavior/though/vibe to..." with a negative connotation, as well as physically "have bad smell of..."

おっさんくさい can be used in both ways, but in the context of 推しの子, Ruby states that Aqua have behavior/thought similar to that of old men for long.